# How to display thumbnails in Wordpress for related posts by author?

Tags: wordpress

I have a related posts by author function using this code:

```
function get_related_author_posts() {
global $authordata, $post;

$authors_posts = get_posts( array( 'author' => $authordata->ID, 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );

$output = '<div class="block">';
foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>';
}
$output .= '</div>';

return $output; }
```

To output I use the following code inside the loop of my single.php file:

```
 <?php echo get_related_author_posts(); ?>
```

Currently the function it displays only post titles as links.

**How should look this wp code in order to display thumbnails for this related posts by author function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
foreach ( $authors_posts as $authors_post ) {
  $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID);
  $output .= '<a href="' . get_permalink( $authors_post->ID ) . '">' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $authors_post->post_title, $authors_post->ID ) . '</a>';
}
$output .= '</div>';
```

check [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) for more information like image size and attributes like extra classes.
Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: It only show the current post thumbnail (the same image), 10 times. I tried $output .= get_the_post_thumbnail($authors_post->ID, 'related-thumb'); but it only show 8 thumbnails instead of 10.

Comment: are you sure all those posts have images? what if you skip the `'related-thumb'` argument?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The related-thumb argument is about thumbnail size.

Comment: Found it. It was an issue related to a plugin. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I hope it wasn't my plugin ;) http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/default-featured-image/

Comment: Far from it :) Thanks anyway!